# How to apply css in angular js using ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I want to apply css styles from external css file. i have defined .container class in css file i want to call it in angular js file using ng-class. But it is not working y.
**style.css**

```
.container
{
width:900px;
height:600px;
border:1px solid;
margin:auto 0;
position:absolute;
background:red;
}
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/Angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"  />
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-class="container" >

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ng-class is used to set the classes dynamically in an angular way i.e., ng-class={{container}} . In the above case you can try like this class="ngClass: container"

Comment: Why not set it in html `class="container"`? Is there a particular reason why you need to use `ng-class`?

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
ng-class="{'container'：true}"
```

see [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 1):

To apply a class like that, you can simply use `class`:

```
<div ng-app="" class="container" >
               ^^^^^
```

From the ***[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)***:

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

If you still want to use `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-class="{'container':true}" >
```

An example ***[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6768/)***

Comment: i know to do it in that way. i want to use ng-class

Comment: @bharath `ng-class` is used to apply classes dynamically based on conditions. It is not required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is no ng-class, but a regular class. the ng-class directive is to do more than just assigning a class, but for example assign the class through a condition. If you simply do like this:

`<div ng-app="" class="container">`

is sufficient.